# Visual Studio 2012 - cannot run project in 32bit (0xc000007b error)

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I want to run project, in Visual Studio 2012 with OpenCV library, which is x86 (32 bit). My PC is 64bit.

Some screens showing my setup:

**When i run application .exe file - it runs as 32bit.** I get weird error with **0xc000007b** code.

[image]

**Dependency Walker shows some errors**
[image]

**Platform is set to 32bit**
[image]

**Machine Target:** is also set to **X86**.

**And one more screen that might be helpfull - it shows that platform is x64?**
[image]

I don't know what is going on, but i read that error 0xc000007b is about some 32 - 64 bit issues.

**[edit]**
VC++ Directories:

[image]

**OpenCV lib path:** There is a plenty of *opencv...* files in that folder.
[image]

**[SOLVED]**

Thanks to **@Miki**. I had to change Lib and System PATH to point on VC11 compile version of Visual Studio 2012. So this works for me **"C:\openCV\build\x86\vc11\bin"**

Comment: The last screenshot is not showing that the platform is x64, it's showing that you can create x64 as a *new* platform. Anyway, Dependency Walker is telling you what the problem is: your application references modules intended for different CPU types. One or more of the libraries used by your app are probably targeting x64.

Comment: Please show your Library Directories under Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories

Comment: @Miki, i edited post and added screen with it

Comment: Where do you link with OpenCV? I'd like to see the OpenCV lib path you're using.

Comment: @Miki, i added path and piece of folder too.

Comment: OK, you're using vc12 compiler, which is for VisualStudio 2013. Since you're using VisualStudio 2012, you need to use vc11 compiler. Change to `... \vc11\lib`

Comment: I changed it and still the same error **0xc000007b**

Comment: Be sure not to use debug libs in release, and viceversa. Also, did you put dll into executable folder, or added the dll folder to system PATH?

Comment: System PATH was wrong, it was pointing to "C:\openCV\build\x86\vc12\bin", so i changed VC to 11 but needed to restart PC... and then it worked!
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're linking to `vc12` libs, i.e. libraries compiled for Visual Studio 2013. Since you're using Visual Studio 2012. you should use `vc11` compiler. So:

- Change the library folder to `...\vc11\lib`.
- Also, be sure that:

  - you copied all required dll into the .exe folder, or
  - you put the `...\vc11\bin` into system PATH